# Java event handling on DefaultTableModel when a cell is clicked

Tags: java, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel

How can I perform a mouse event handling when clicking a cell on my `DefaultTableModel` for example when clicking the first column of a row it prints the whole row.

```
static DefaultTableModel dTableModel = new DefaultTableModel(databaseInfo, columns){
        public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
            Class returnValue;

            // Verifying that the column exists (index > 0 && index < number of columns

            if ((column >= 0) && (column < getColumnCount())) {
              returnValue = getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
            } else {

              // Returns the class for the item in the column   

              returnValue = Object.class;
            }
            return returnValue;
          }
        };
```

thank you .

Comment: Have you tried adding a MouseLstener to the JTable?

Comment: i want to add it after but don't know how.thanks

Answer (score 2):

> how can i perfom a mouse event handling when clicking a cell on my DefaultTableModel

The DefaultTableModel has nothing to do with mouse clicks. A TableModel contains the data that is displayed by the table.

> for example when clicking the first column of a row it prints the whole row.

Maybe you want to display a "button" the indicates to the user what will happen when you activate the button, either by a mouse click or by using the keyboard?

If so then check out [Table Button Column](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/) for one solution.